# Can we Change Classic Email Template type in Salesforce?

Tags: email-template, vs-code, salesforce-classic

I want to change HTML type classic email template to either Custom or Visualforce. I tried manually overriding the meta file but it yielded nothing. Is there any other workaound?

Comment: i don't think this is possible

Comment: I tried manually overriding the XML to VF, and it got deployed . But I'm stuck at the .email file . I am able to deploy it without any error but the email template remains unchanged. And when I'm trying to edit the template in org I'm getting following error: Markup can only be specified for template of type Visualforce
It's weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to update/change template type once it is created. You would need to create a new template.

Check more [details](https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000i3zYAAQ) and [limitations](https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000i3zYAAQ) here.

Thanks